# iPhone app freezes after deleting from multitasking tray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, crash, multitasking

My app works fine when launching from XCode, and it starts back up from a saved state fine, but the problem is when I open the multitasking tray and manually close the app.  After closing the app this way, when the app reopens it doesn't start from the loading screen, it starts from the screen it was at when it was closed, but it is frozen and pushing the home button from this state causes springboard to crash.

My first thought was that the app was taking too long to open, so in the applicationDidFinishLaunching function I load data in a new thread (I have also tried performSelectorInBackground and performSelector after delay) and this works fine except for the strange problem described above.

Also, nothing is written to the device log and no crash report is created.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the Xcode debugger still attached when you shut down the app?  That would cause the behavior you're seeing when you terminate the app from the task bar.

Comment: Yep, that was the problem.  If I build the app for distribution and load it onto my iPhone with the iPhone Configuration Utility it works as expected.  Thanks for the quick answer!